# Response.Redirect in MVC 4 Mobile Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile web application using ASP.NET mvc 4. I am facing problem with response.redirect to some other website (eg: http://www.google.com) from my controller,it is showing "Error Loading Page" message without redirect.

I have tried the following codes to redirect under "About" action on Home controller:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com"); 

return RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");

response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

All the above produced the same error.

Note: the hyperlinks in view pages are working fine

Thanks

Comment: `return Redirect("http://google.com");` would work. There must be something else going on.

Comment: a code example of your JQM page may lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting up your link to the controller...you need to make sure the `data-ajax` attribute is set to `false`.

```
<a href="/MyRedirectingController" data-ajax="false">Redirect</a>
```

My understanding is that jQuery mobile wraps all anchor request in ajax, unless otherwise specified, and your response.redirect is just being served to the jQuery `.done` function which can't handle it properly.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

> Important: rel="external" and $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false
>
> Slightly different implementations of the replaceState API in various
>   browsers can cause odd behavior in specific scenarios. For example,
>   some browser implementations (including desktop browsers) implement
>   the popstate event differently when linking externally and moving back
>   to a page onto which state has already been pushed/replaced. When
>   building a jQuery Mobile application where the Ajax navigation is
>   being explicitly disabled, either through the frequent use of
>   rel="external" on links or by disabling Ajax navigation completely via
>   the $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false, we recommend disabling the pushState
>   feature to fall back to the hash based navigation for more consistent
>   behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you are redirecting outside local site.

See this part of the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

> Hash values created by jQuery Mobile are normalized as full paths
>   relative to the URL of the first "real" page that was loaded.

Then later it confirms the "local" requirement here:

> When a link is clicked, jQuery Mobile will make sure that the link is
>   referencing a local URL

I think the solution is to not redirect users to other domains.

**UPDATE**

The above solution highlights the wrong part of the problem but the solution may still be the same.  You should use javascript to do the redirection such as:

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

I believe you will run into issues if your JQM solution is attempting to make an ajax call that is then redirecting.  One issue, specifically for google.com, could be if you are signed in to google. It will then redirect you to `https` for example.  That could be interfering with the JQM / `window.location.hash`.

Comment: The redirect is happening at the controller/action level and not within the site; as such, jQuery Mobile should have no relevance. (unless it's a call being made by jQuery mobile to attempt to load the page using Ajax. if that was your intent, i misread and apologize).

Comment: @BradChristie - I believe you are correct, my initial answer may cite unrelated parts of the JQM documentation.  I think the answer is still to not redirect at the controller/action level.  A javascript solution seems to be preferred.